# 4d monte carlo integration R

Tags: r, integration, montecarlo

How to integrate function using the Monte Carlo method

```
F(X[1],X[2],X[3],X[4])
```

Which depends on 4 variable by 4 dimensions?

I mean `int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} X[1]X[2]X[3]X[4] dX[1] dX[2] dX[3] dX[4]`

UPD
function is

```
data1 =  rnorm(100, 0, 1)
data2 =  rnorm(100, 0.1, 0.5)
data3 =  rnorm(100, 0.2, 0.8)
data4 =  rnorm(100, 0.3, 0.9)

kernel1 = kdensity(data1,kernel = 'gaussian')
kernel2 = kdensity(data2,kernel = 'gaussian')
kernel3 = kdensity(data3,kernel = 'gaussian')
kernel4 = kdensity(data4,kernel = 'gaussian')


f <- function(X) {
  return(X[1]*kernel1(X[1])*kernel2(X[2])*kernel3(X[3])*kernel4(X[4]))
}
```

and i want to integrate it

`int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} int_{0}^{1} f dX[1] dX[2] dX[3] dX[4]`

Comment: Can you post the function and the set on which it is to be integrated?

Comment: @RuiBarradas i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to your particular structure of integral expression, you can rewrite your nested integral into a product of integrals.

Thus, the solution below may be a example (with random seed `set.seed(1)`) for you:

```
g <- Vectorize(function(ker) {integrate(ker,0,1)}$value)
gE <- function(ker) {integrate(function(x) x*ker(x),0,1)}$value
res1 <- prod(c(gE(kernel1),g(c(kernel2,kernel3,kernel4))))
```

such that

```
> res1
[1] 0.01559343
```

**Nested Integral**: you need to rewrite your function `f` first, i.e.,

```
f <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4) {
  return(x1*kernel1(x1)*kernel2(x2)*kernel3(x3)*kernel4(x4))
}

res2 <- integrate(Vectorize(function(x4) 
  integrate(Vectorize(function(x3,x4) 
    integrate(Vectorize(function(x2,x3,x4) 
      integrate(f,0,1,x2,x3,x4)$value),
      0,
      1,
      x3,
      x4)$value),
    0,
    1,
    x4)$value),
  0,
  1)$value
```

such that

```
> res2
[1] 0.01559343
```

Comment: And without production of integrals it is impossible?

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков in that case maybe you need a long nested expression for the integral...

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков see my updated solution for your quested nested integral

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков the nested version is rather slow when you have multiple variables, so I suggest you simplify the   expression first (like the first approach)